# Getting Forbidding error while trying to tweak a sentiment analyses bot

Tags: python, twitterapi-python

So i was finding older versions of sentiment bots i could tweak and reuse and found this one from 9m ago but its giving me forbiddion error when i try to connect to twiiter api(error is below)
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

any idea on whats wrong?

```
import os
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob

# Authenticate with Twitter API
consumer_key = os.getenv('')
consumer_secret = os.getenv('')
access_token = os.getenv('')
access_token_secret = os.getenv('')

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('', '')
auth.set_access_token('', '')

api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Search for tweets about the Warriors
warriors_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q='#GoldenStateWarriors', lang="en").items(1000)

# Perform sentiment analysis on tweets
positive_tweets = 0
negative_tweets = 0
neutral_tweets = 0

for tweet in warriors_tweets:
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
        positive_tweets += 1
    elif analysis.sentiment.polarity < 0:
        negative_tweets += 1
    else:
        neutral_tweets += 1

# Print results
print("Positive tweets: ", positive_tweets)
print("Negative tweets: ", negative_tweets)
print("Neutral tweets: ", neutral_tweets)
```

i tried managing twitter api premssions but lack knowledge on the api usage

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `api.search_tweets` is no longer available in the Free access level. To use it, you can upgrade to the Basic access level.

Comment: With free access, it is not even possible to post a simple tweet? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76419375/5029509

Comment: @Questioner yes, it is. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76453784/96313